# How to set version of indexed database in HTML 5

Tags: html, indexeddb

I am creating a HTML 5 web application, I am using indexed db on local storage, I am facing a issue while setting the database version in the HTML 5 indexed database

The code  snippet is as follow

```
try {
                var request = iDB.open('travelDB', dbVersion);
                request.onerror = function (event) { errorDisplay('Failed to open IndexedDB database.'); }
                request.onsuccess = function (event) {
                    db = request.result;  // set the global db variable


                    db.onerror = dbErrorHandler;



                    alert(db.version != dbNewVersion);
                    if (db.version != dbNewVersion) {
                        alert('game begins');
                        db.setVersion(dbNewVersion);  
                       // var req = db.setAttribute(version, dbNewVersion);
                        alert('game ends');
                        req.onerror = function (event) { alert('version error: ' + event.target.errorCode); }
                        req.onsuccess = function (event) {
                            alert('Creating the object store');
                            var objectStore = db.createObjectStore('oTravel', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
                            objectStore.createIndex('traveler', 'ciTraveler', { unique: false });
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                dispError('Browser supports IndexedDB but didn\'t open the database. (' + e.message + ')');
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe setVersion is deprecated. Just specify a newer version to indexedDB.open and use the onupgradeneeded callback to perform an upgrade.